# libtorrent speed greater limits

Tags: c++, libtorrent

I'm tring to use libtorrent library and I have a some following problem.

I create torrents with default settings and set them limits (e.g., 100Kb) as

```cpp
    torrent_handle.set_download_limit(limit);
```

And when I ask speed for the current torrent:

```cpp
    torrent_handle.status ().download_payload_rate
```

sometimes I get greater value then the limit (e.g., about 200Kb or 300Kb).

What's wrong? Why my torrent limits aren't applyed?

Comment: What if you set the limit much smaller?  Does it have any effect?

Comment: upload_payload_rate jumps anyway

Comment: try to disable uTP that should fix it. Also are you on unix or windows?

Comment: I've set: settings.rate_limit_ip_overhead = false; settings.rate_limit_utp = false; But unfortunately no result

Comment: in your example you're setting the download rate limit, but you inspect the upload rate. i.e. the upload rate won't be directly impacted by setting the download rate limit

Comment: I'm sorry. Wrong example. I mean download_payload_rate.